# Android - Changing the size of a view inside viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

So.. I'm currently trying to change two views inside `ViewPager` to take half of the `ViewPager` size each. The `ViewPager` itself is set to take 75% of screen size.

Here's a part of the xml code for the `ViewPager`

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_relativeViewPagerWrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:measureAllChildren="false"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the `ViewPagerAdapter` as an adapter for `ViewPager`

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    int[] title;
    int[] message;
    int[] background;
    int[] image;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] title, int[] message,
                            int[] background, int[] image) {
        this.context = context;
        this.title = title;
        this.message = message;
        this.background = background;
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return title.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView titleText;
        TextView messageText;
        RelativeLayout slidingBackground;
        ImageView slidingImage;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
                false);

        // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
        titleText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_item_titleText);
        messageText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_item_messageText);

        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        titleText.setText(title[position]);
        messageText.setText(message[position]);

        // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
        slidingBackground = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_item_slidingBackground);
        slidingImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_item_slidingImage);
        // Capture position and set to the ImageView
        slidingBackground.setBackgroundResource(background[position]);
        slidingImage.setImageResource(image[position]);

        // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

    }
}
```

`LayoutResize` class

```
public class LayoutResize extends Activity{

    public DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    public int width(int sizeX, DisplayMetrics displayMetrics)
    {
        int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels * sizeX / 100;
        return screenWidth;
    }

    public int height(int sizeY, DisplayMetrics displayMetrics)
    {
        int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels * sizeY / 100;
        return screenHeight;
    }
}
```

Anddd the main class where I resize layouts

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main_mainLayout);
        //RelativeLayout viewPagerItem = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.viewPagerItem);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View pagerItemInflater = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, mainLayout);
        View viewpager_items = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, mainLayout, true);
        //setContentView(pagerItemInflater);

        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        LayoutResize layoutResize = new LayoutResize();

        RelativeLayout relativeViewPager =(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_relativeViewPagerWrapper);
        int relativeViewPagerHeight = layoutResize.height(75, displayMetrics);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewPagerParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)relativeViewPager.getLayoutParams();
        viewPagerParams.height = relativeViewPagerHeight;
        relativeViewPager.setLayoutParams(viewPagerParams);

        RelativeLayout slidingBackground =(RelativeLayout) pagerItemInflater.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_item_slidingBackground);
        int slidingBackgroundHeight = layoutResize.height(38, displayMetrics);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams slidingBackgroundParams = slidingBackground.getLayoutParams();
        slidingBackgroundParams.height = slidingBackgroundHeight;
        slidingBackground.setLayoutParams(slidingBackgroundParams);

        RelativeLayout slidingImageWrapper = (RelativeLayout) pagerItemInflater.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_item_slidingImageWrapper);
        int slidingImageWrapperHeight = layoutResize.height(37, displayMetrics);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams slidingImageWrapperParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)slidingImageWrapper.getLayoutParams();
        slidingImageWrapperParams.height = slidingImageWrapperHeight;
        slidingImageWrapper.setLayoutParams(slidingImageWrapperParams);
```

Both `slidingImageWrapper` and `slidingBackground` are inside the `ViewPager`. Their sizes doesn't change when I put them to 37% and 38% respectively.

Am I doing stuffs wrong here? How can I change the view inside the adapter itself? Or it is even not possible? If it is not possible, then.. Any suggestion?

UPDATE :
[image: ViewPager]
This is the `Activity` using `ViewPager`. Everything above the grey box is the `ViewPager` which can slide around the `ViewPager. The grey box takes approximately 20% of screen height, the orange box takes approximately 30% of screen height, and the rest is 50%.
The orange box is made up of`RelativeLayout`wrapping`TextView`. The problem is by wrapping it, the orange box will not have a fixed size. It depends on the`TextView`.. I want it to take 30% of the screen using`displayMetrics`..

Update :

Here's my current pager adapter

```
public class MainActivityViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    private Context context;
    List<MainActivityModel> mDataset = new ArrayList<>();

    public MainActivityViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mDataset = MainActivityDataSource.getData(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        // Declare Variables
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_mainactivity, container,
                false);

        // Sliding Background
        ImageView slidingBackground = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_mainactivity_slidingBackground);
        slidingBackground.setImageResource(mDataset.get(position).background);

        // Sliding MI
        ImageView slidingMI = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_mainactivity_miImage) ;
        slidingMI.setImageResource(mDataset.get(position).imageMI);

        // Sliding Title
        OpenSansFont slidingTitle = (OpenSansFont)itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_mainactivity_titleText);
        slidingTitle.setText(Utilities.openSansFontify(context, Constants.semiBold, mDataset.get(position).title));

        slidingTitle.setTextSize((int) (context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_size_large) / context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        slidingMI.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (position == mDataset.size() - 1){
            slidingMI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            slidingTitle.setText(Utilities.openSansFontify(context, Constants.regular, mDataset.get(position).title));
            slidingTitle.setTextSize((int) (context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_size) / context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        }

        // Add viewpager_mainactivityvity.xml to ViewPager
        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_mainactivityvity.xml from ViewPager
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want the `ViewPager`'s children to be smaller than the `ViewPager`? Why is reducing the ViewPager itself not good enough? The purpose of the ViewPager is to manage switching between the children. So in essence each child would be the same size as the ViewPager. Also, what would be in the remaining space left over?

Comment: Updated the question, the reason is stated there now :) is it possible tho?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer! Hopefully people with similar problem will be helped by this :

I've failed to realize that actually everything was initialized in the adapter and used in the main layout. Bad thing to do when you are using someone else's adapter and only knowing how to **change the values** in the adapter, not **how it works**

So I've added the usual call to the layout in the `ViewPagerAdapter`

```
RelativeLayout slidingBackground = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_item_slidingBackground);
```

And then do stuffs to it like..

```
slidingBackground = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_item_slidingBackground);
        int slidingBackgroundHeight = layoutResize.height(30);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams slidingBackgroundParams = slidingBackground.getLayoutParams();
        slidingBackgroundParams.height = slidingBackgroundHeight;
```

Those are done **inside the `ViewPagerAdapter`**

So I can't change the values thru the class which the `ViewPager` is used in, but I have to change the value of the adapter itself.

Comment: Can you post the ViewPager's Adapter?

Comment: @murt Yes, I'm going to post it now, but it's quite different from back then at January, design changed and I changed several stuffs